# Splitting XML file with XSLT based on nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm starting to learn more about using XSLT to parse XML - but even after researching other solutions, I"m still unable to correctly write a stylesheet that will break up a large XML file into smaller XML files based on nodes.

I've got a large XML file that has 1500 or so abstracts. The structure of that file looks like:

```
<rows>
    <row>
    <ID>P-1-28-08</ID>
    <ABSNO>4286</ABSNO>
    <title>..article title...</title>
    <topic>..article topics..</topic>
    <authors>..article authors..</authors>
    <abstract>..article abstract..</abstract>
    <keywords>..article keywords..</keywords>
    </row>

    <row>
    <ID>P-1-28-09</ID>
    <ABSNO>4461</ABSNO>
    <title>..article title...</title>
    <topic>..article topics..</topic>
    <authors>..article authors..</authors>
    <abstract>..article abstract..</abstract>
    <keywords>..article keywords..</keywords>
    </row>

    <row>
    <ID>P-1-28-10</ID>
    <ABSNO>4056</ABSNO>
    <<title>..article title...</title>
    <topic>..article topics..</topic>
    <authors>..article authors..</authors>
    <abstract>..article abstract..</abstract>
    <keywords>..article keywords..</keywords>
    </row>
<rows>
```

The output I'm looking for is to have each `<row>` node be its own XML file with the `<ABSNO>` node as its filename.

Is this something that can be done by running the original XML file through a stylesheet? Anyone have time to help me see what that would look like?

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:result-document>` should make a job. Just very simple example (expecting document node `<rows>` in original xml file).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/rows/row">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{ABSNO}.xml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Okay  - thanks, Jirka. That styleshet did create a file that had all the nodes within <row> dumped into a string of text. 

Going further - I'm looking to create a series of XML files based on each <row> that still maintain the node structure. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually not... it produced three xml files for me each containing one of row elements. So what is expected output?

Comment: @HalAtkins, your comment that the "styleshet did create a file that had all the nodes within <row> dumped into a string of text" suggests the XML is different from the one you posted. Any chance it has some `xmlns="foo"` on the root element? In that case add `<xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-namespace="foo" ...>` on Jirka's code (of course with `foo` being replaced with the namespace defined in the input XML.

Comment: Yes, I actually had a couple of things I had to clean up (it did have some unneeded items in the root element). Furthermore, I needed to go in and wrap the contents of most of the nodes in <![CDATA[ ]]>.

For now, this is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate the help from Jirka and Martin!